# Why is my Record of Type sort showing as Set sort?

Tags: coq

When I use the Record macro to create a record type, it shows up as a Set sort instead of Type sort.

I created a minimal test example that shows the same behavior:

```
Record little_test : Type :=
  {
    bit1 : nat;
    bit2 : nat;
  }.

Check little_test.
```

```
little_test
     : Set
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Set` is simply the lowest level in the infinite hierarchy of `Type`. Because Coq's universes are cumulative, that means that `little_test` also inhabits every higher level too. Generally you don't want to restrict your types to only be in higher levels, so Coq simply minimizes the universe level. If you really want `little_test` to be in a higher level, you can explicitly ask for it.

If you're using CoqIDE, set "Display universe levels" in the View menu instead of `Set Printing Universes.`. The other IDEs (Proof General, etc.) may also have their own way to show universe levels.

```
Set Printing Universes.

Record little_test@{i} : Type@{i} :=
  {
    bit1 : nat;
    bit2 : nat;
  }.

Check little_test.
```

This approach declares a fixed universe level (`little_set.i`) and forces little_set to inhabit `Type@{little_test.i}`. If you already have a universe level from somewhere else, you can leave off the declaration of the universe level.

```
Set Printing Universes.

Record little_test1@{i} : Type@{i} :=
  {
    bit1 : nat;
    bit2 : nat;
  }.

Record little_test2 : Type@{little_test1.i} :=
  {
    bit3 : nat;
    bit4 : nat;
  }.

Check little_test1.
Check little_test2.
```

In this approach, `little_test1` and `little_test2` have the same minimum level (but remember that universe cumulativity means that they both inhabit every higher level).

This final approach declares infinitely many `little_test`s — one for each universe level.

```
Set Printing Universes.
Unset Universe Minimization ToSet.

Polymorphic Record little_test@{i} : Type@{i} :=
  {
    bit1 : nat;
    bit2 : nat;
  }.

Check little_test.
```

By default, though, Coq will minimize the universe level when you use `little_test` without a universe parameter (to `Set` if no constraint exists), so we have to `Unset Universe Minimization ToSet` to change this behavior. If you want all of your `Record`s and `Inductive` types to be polymorphic like this, you can `Set Universe Polymorphism`. Note that you still have to use `@{i}` (or some other name for the universe level) to indicate where the polymorphism is.